# Craeting QueueTable in OracleAQ 11.2.0

Tags: queue, jms, oracle11g, message-queue, oracle-aq

I have installed Oracle11.2.0(windows,32 bit) and tried to create a queuetable..
(I have granted all permissions for the jmsuser,AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE,AQ_USER_ROLE,DB_Access).

when try to create a queuetable, Oracle gives following issue;

oracle.jms.AQjmsException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 81

My sample code is as follows,

```
  createQueue(Session session) {
    AQQueueTableProperty qt_prop;
    AQQueueTable q_table;
    AQjmsDestinationProperty dest_prop;
    Queue queue;
    qt_prop = new AQQueueTableProperty("SYS.AQ$_JMS_BYTES_MESSAGE");

    /* create a queue table */
    q_table = ((AQjmsSession) session).createQueueTable("jmsuser", "test_queue_table",
                                                                qt_prop);

    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The error message says it's an authentication problem (username or password), not an authorization (grants) problem. Are you sure you're using valid username and passwords to connect to the database? Did you put username and password in the connection string or are you providing it seperately?

Comment: Yes i can connect to my user via sqlplus and sqldeveloper...Before creating table i have following lines and connection was established successfully.                                                          
QFac = AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(hostname, oracle_sid, portno, driver);                                                             QCon = QFac.createQueueConnection(userName, password);              session = QCon.createQueueSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);                                         QCon.start();          After that,try to create table but couldn't..:(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with following setting;

ALTER SYSTEM GLOBAL_TOPIC_ENABLED = FALSE;